# Read rows in batches from mysql in constant time

Tags: mysql

I am reading rows from a mysql table in batches of 100

```
select * from Foo limit 1000, 100
```

This works. but the time taken by the query increases drastically as the offset is increased. I think the reason is that the database still reads the entire result before returning the last 100.

Is there a way I can read rows in batches and in constant time between batches?

Comment: Your batch size is 100, not 1000.

Comment: corrected the text.